# How to get verbiage included in output

Tags: c

I would like to have the displayed answers to include the words; slice, fruits, bags or teaspoons following the calculated number.  All my attempts have been futile. Any support would be greatly appreciated.

```c
include <stdio.h>
void calorie(long, int *, int *, int *, int *);
int main()
{
  long total;
  int pizza, chips, apples, mustard;
  printf("How many calories do you want to consume during your meal? ");
  scanf("%ld", &total);
  calorie(total, &pizza, &chips, &apples, &mustard);
  printf("Pizza:   %2d\n", pizza);
  printf("Chips:   %2d\n", chips);
  printf("Apples:  %2d\n", apples);
  printf("Mustard: %2d\n", mustard);
  return 0;
}

void calorie(long total, int *pizza, int *chips, int *apples, int *mustard)
{
  const int per_pizza = 385;
  const int per_chips = 170;
  const int per_apples = 80;
  const int per_mustard = 5;
  *pizza = total / per_pizza;
  total -= *pizza * per_pizza;
  *chips = total / per_chips;
  total -= *chips * per_chips;
  *apples = total / per_apples;
  total -= *apples * per_apples;
  *mustard = total / per_mustard;
  total -= *mustard * per_mustard;
}
```

Comment: You simply ask how to print the names before the numbers? please be more specific.

Comment: `printf("Pizza:   %2d slice(s)\n", pizza);`? Here `%2d` gets replaced with the value of `pizza`, everything else is printed verbatim.

Comment: FYI you can simplify the total updates: `total %= per_pizza;`

Comment: My apologies.  If I enter the total number of calories I want to consume and the output states Pizza: 2, how can I make it show Pizza: 2 slices, Chips: 2 to Chips: 2 bags, etc.  Not only how I can have the program display like this, but why the code allows that to happen.  Looking to also learn vs get answers.  Thanx

Comment: How many calories do you want to consume during your meal? 2000
Pizza:    5
Chips:    0
Apples:   0
Mustard: 15

Comment: I would like the output to include the words slices, bag, whole and tsp: such as: How many calories do you want to consume during your meal? 2000
Pizza:    5 slices
Chips:    0 bag/s
Apples:   0 whole
Mustard: 15 tsp